# Partial shade on west-facing slope. Need help designing grape / fruit vineyard

Tags: fruit-trees, grape-vine, shade

I'm looking for help placing espaliered fruit trees / grapes for the best sun / shade combination.

We have a westward-facing slope that we want to start a grape / fruit vineyard with. It gets approximately 5 to 5 1/2 hours of sunlight, with partial shade through 60 foot Norway Spruce trees from the East, South, and West. We are in Zone 6, but in a valley, so it acts like 5b.

We are going to grow everything on vines / trellis, including the fruit (apple/pear will be grown cordon, rest of fruit will be grown fan espalier).

We get shade in the middle of the day about 30 ft. in from the south. That area gets morning and afternoon sun though.

The west side gets shade starting around 5pm, about 30 ft. in.

The east side gets shade in the morning until around 11am.

Is it better to have certain varieties in certain areas, or in the end will it not matter? For instance, I've heard grapes like morning sun, so would it be better to place the grapes where the proposed plum / apple vines are now? I've heard Cherry will be least tolerant of shade, should I place that further in the middle of the field?

Any help would be great appreciated! I am installing all of the 10' wood poles and ordering plants this fall, in anticipation of planting in the Spring.

[image: Proposed Layout]